# Android FFMPEG slow

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I create a video with an overlay fading to merge this later with another video to get an overlayed video.
 Merging and co are working fine and fast, but creating the overlay-video with a fading picture is very slow (3 to 4 fps). Other operations like scaling run with 10 to 200 fps.
Here is my ffmpeg command for creating the ovleray video.

```
../binary/ffmpeg -loop 1 -i ../overlay_0.png -t 21.534 -vf scale=1280:720,fade=in:st=21.034:d=0.05,fade=out:st=21.534:d=2.0 -pix_fmt rgba -vcodec png -threads 5 -preset ultrafast ../outfile.mp4
```

Did I miss any commands to speed this up?

Comment: Hey I have been searching on this kind of stuff since few days can you guide me how did you do this? Thanks.

Comment: There was not really a guidable way, just Google and Trial&Error